# Why does this simple string formating now throw exception?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm using Authorize.net API and they require card expiration field to be formated as "yyyy-mm". We did that with this simple line of code:

`expirationDate = model.Year.ToString("D4") & "-" & model.Month.ToString("D2")`

and this absolutelly worked. I still have cards stored in the system that were saved using this method! But today I was testing something completelly unrelated, and wanted to add another card, and bam, this code exploded with this exception:

`System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "D4" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'`

Inner exception to that one is:

`Input string was not in a correct format.`

This just... doesn't make sense to me. Why in the world is it trying to convert format specifier (D4) into an integer? What input string? What in the world changed in two days?

Comment: What type is `Year` ?

Comment: @Nitram - your question actually got me on right track. The type is Integer?, that is nullable int. The value is still correct, but toString() seems to work differently for nullable types. We changed them from int to int? few days ago because it made more sense for our front end, and this stopped working... any ideas why?

Comment: I can tell you why it can't work. But I do not get why you receive even that error message. I get a message that I am using a non-existing overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are using a [`Nullable(Of Integer)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx). This is a different structure that does not support the overloads of the `ToString` method a normal `Integer` has.

You can view the overloads of the `Nullable` structure [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx).

I suggest you use the `GetValueOrDefault()` method to get the proper `Integer` and also apply the value you expect in case the value is `Nothing`.

If it is impossible that a instance with a `Nothing` set for the year reaches this method you can simply use the `Value` property.

I still do not fully understand why you get this strange error message. Maybe you could check out what the actual method that is called is? Pointing at the method should give you that information. It can't be `Nullable(Of Integer).ToString`

Comment: Yeah, it's extremely weird. I'll try to step in the debugger and see where it takes me.

Comment: It is calling `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value)` according to stack trace.

Comment: My guess for the strange error is that since you can call functions without parens in VB.NET, the compiler sees it as `model.Year.ToString()("D4")` - i.e. it is trying to use the "D4" as character index of the value returned by `ToString`, so it needs to convert it to an integer.  I think this would only compile with `Option Strict Off`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workable solution and something of an answer thanks to @Nitram's comment. The type of Year/Month property has been changed from `Integer` to `Integer?`. Obviously, this isn't a very satisfying answer because I still don't understand why the nullable int can't be formatted, and yet the code compiles perfectly. The working solution for me has been using static format method on String as so:

`expirationDate = String.Format("{0:D4}-{1:D2}", model.Year, model.Month)`

This works fine even with nullable types.

Comment: Is this properly working even if `Year` is `Nothing`?

Comment: @Nitram - to be honest I have no idea, it's already constrained to only valid credit card years and validated before it reaches this point and I don't have time to test it right now.